# Select IN from a CSV field

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have the following in a MySQL db

```
CHILDREN 
|NAME |LIKES (LONGTEXT)
|Sam  |75
|John |58,64,75

FRUITS 
|ID |LABEL
|58 |Apple
|64 |Banana
|75 |Cherry
```

In order to obtain fruit names for children I do:

```
> select * from fruits where id in 
(select LIKES from CHILDREN where name="Sam");
|ID |LABEL
|75 |Cherry
```

OK, but

```
> select * from fruits where id in 
(select LIKES from CHILDREN where name="John");
|ID |LABEL
|58 |Apple
```

I tried also the following with the same result:

```
> select * from fruits where id in ("58,64,75")
|ID |LABEL
|58 |Apple
[Main Instruction]
Your query produced 1 warnings.
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '58,64,75'
[OK]

>select * from fruits where id in (58,64,75)
|ID |LABEL
|58 |Apple
|64 |Banana
|75 |Cherry
```

How is it possible to fix the problem **WITHOUT changing the tables definition** and things like this...

Comment: wow you like to mix and match don't you.

Comment: What is the output structure you need?

Comment: If you are stuck with the tables, that is one thing.  If you designed them, you should learn how to design SQL tables properly.

Comment: The output structure should be like the last good "manual" output from the OP (without quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question you mentioned `fix the problem WITOUT changing the tables definition` , there is a solution for that using `find_in_set` function. But the ideal solution is to normalize the data so as to avoid comma-separation data storage. In the long run it will bring up more difficulties. So you must normalize the table.

However using `find_in_set` you can achieve what you are looking now as

```
select
f.* from FRUITS f
join CHILREN c on find_in_set(f.ID,c.LIKES) > 0 
where c.NAME = 'John'
```

Comment: Hoping that after coma will not be spaces or 0s (`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('12','1,2,120,012, 12')` gives `0`), this is an acceptable solution!

Comment: Yes space will mess up and if you think there are spaces you can replace them `select FIND_IN_SET('12',replace('1,2,120,112, 012, 12',' ','')) ;`